# html-php form code not executing

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to execute this html form code, the php script is not executing properly. Can you point out the problems?

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">

<p>
  <input type="text" name="titles[]" /><br />
  <textarea name="languages[]" ></textarea><br />
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" name="titles[]" /><br />
  <textarea name="languages[]" ></textarea><br />
</p>
```

## php script

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $k=0;
  foreach($_POST['languages'] as $language) {
    echo $language = htmlentities($language);
    echo $title    = $_POST['titles'][$k];
    $k++;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not executing properly ?

Comment: Can you tell the SO community what the error message is? That's a great help when posting

Comment: on a correct markup note, under HTML5 rules those `< />` for input and br elements are not required (and will in fact be completely ignored). Simply use `<input...>` and `<br>`. On an actual question note, "not executing properly" is an opinion, not an error. So: what do you think it should be doing, what is it doing instead, and what makes you think that it should be doing what you expected, instead?

Comment: I am not sure why you are echoing $title = instead of just the $_POST variable same with the $language =

Comment: I've just replicated this code and it works fine. What HTML code are you using after your second input / text area block? Do you have the submit button in there?

Comment: Where is your submit button ?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<p>
  <input type="text" name="titles[]" /><br />
  <textarea name="languages[]" ></textarea><br />
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" name="titles[]" /><br />
  <textarea name="languages[]" ></textarea><br />
</p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

   foreach($_POST['languages'] as $key => $language) {
       echo $language = htmlentities($language);
       echo " -- ";
       echo $title    = $_POST['titles'][$key];
   echo "<br/>";

   }
}
?>
```

Comment: # this code works well, can we add some styles to the php output?

Comment: yes u can .. u just have to add html styling like you may have done in normal way